# How to query how many metrics in a period with Influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

I want to know how many events we send to InfluxDB for a given period. If I use the following query `SELECT COUNT(value) FROM /./ WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY time(10m)`, I get that grouped for each metric but I want the total for all metrics.

If I use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM /./ WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY time(10m)`, I get an error:

> Server returned error: expected field argument in count()

Comment: What are the results of `SHOW FIELD KEYS`?

Comment: Field key is `value` for each metric but when using `SELECT COUNT(value)` I get the result for each metric rather than the total count of metrics values for the time period.

Comment: There is no way to ask the system for a count of all points. This would be similar to asking a relational database how many rows there were in all tables combined, and is not a supported query.

Answer (score 5):

The COUNT function takes one and only one field key as an argument. If you have field keys that are not named `value` you will have to run a separate query to count them.

Alternately, you can run them together like:

`SELECT COUNT(value), COUNT(otherfield), COUNT(anotherfield) FROM /./ WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY time(10m)`

Comment: Thanks @beckettsean. Field key is `value` for each metric but when using `SELECT COUNT(value)` I get the result for each metric rather than the total count of metrics. I just want to see how many metrics in total we're sending to influxdb.